# Difficulty evaluating some votes

Tags: support, voting, user-interface, privileges

Sometimes an answer has a low voting level like 3.

How do I know if this is caused by a few upvotes or approximately the same number of up and down votes?

Comment: Just as an aside, the 'low' voting level is relative. In some tags an answer with 3 votes has been unusually well rewarded.

Comment: How is this question not a duplicate?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot see the exact vote breakdown until you have reached [the "established user"](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) reputation level, 1000 points.

At that point, you can click on the vote tally to see the up and down vote counts:

> [image: Vote counts]

Comment: At that zoom level, voting looks like an Arcade game. Pew pew!

Comment: @Pekka The screenshot's from Arqade, so it's fitting. :)

Comment: Users with less than 1000 rep can use userscripts like [this one](http://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep-less-than-1000) to view the vote breakdown.